# Are some passwords more vulnerable to password crackers?

Tags: passwords

Suppose I have a password made of `n` alphabetic characters. An attacker is given the hashed password and will attempt a brute force attack on cracking it.

I can envision a naive password cracker trying all combinations starting with `AAAA...A` then `AAAA...B` then `AAAA...C` etc until `ZZZZ...Z`. For this attacker, a password that starts with an `A` is going to reduce the time to crack by `25 * 26^(n-1)` (compared to starting with a `Z`).

Of course, you could first try dictionary words, variations of dictionary words, and a list of the most common passwords... but if the password was random garbage then at some point it will have to iterate over the entire character space. And if you didn't iterate over the space in some well defined way (i.e. random inputs), then you would need a mammoth amount of space to remember which inputs you already attempted (and you would have to check against at each iteration, thus slowing things down).

You could parallelize the inputs so you attempt `A...`, `B...`, `C...`, ..., `Z...` at the same time, but at some point you will run out of cores.

How do modern password crackers solve this problem?

Comment: This question does not consider the fact that usually when trying to brute-force passwords, there are multiple  targets (users). It is possible to use all these combinations, and so-on against multiple users. This means: just one of the passwords needs to be very weak, and at least one user password gets broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final part of your question is easy to answer:

They do exactly what you have suggested:

- dictionary words
- common passwords
- faster processors
- more processors

but they also use hash tables or rainbow tables, which allow the attacker to trade off time before getting the hashes with time taken to break afterwards. In simplistic terms they effectively pre-calculate password hashes (not exactly correct - look at our questions on rainbow tables for more info)

The problem itself is why we always recommend long passwords. Above a certain length they are effectively un-brute-forceable in the lifespan of the universe (or other appropriate milestone)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a huge difference between cracking single password hash and set of password hashes.

**It may not be easy to crack single hash, while its trivial to crack some percent of set containing lets say 10.000 hashes.**

Modern password crackers tends to crack sets of hashes, because it benefits more.

Anyway, if you ask about methods, your intuition is right.

Whole story starts from dictionary attacks. Ofcourse dictionary is not set of words only. Good dictionary contains also patterns. For example *qazxswedcvfrtgb* seems quite strong, but if you look at your keyboard, you may notice its obvious pattern.

In real world, where crackers cracks sets of hashes, story ends here. Few-million-word dictionary will allow you to crack from 5% to 50% hashes in set.

Anyway, if set is quite small or you gonna crack single password, that is the point where brute force shows up.

You have mentioned *parallelization*. Nowadays *parallelized* becomes rather *distributed*. If you have some botnet, you can install there MPI or PVM and perform distributed computations. It's really awesome, because its **scalability**.

Answer (score 0):

Real crackers will try the more commonly used passwords first.  They will first use names, dictionary words, lists of known used passwords, and variations on all of these.  Here is a description of one such effort on a list of hashes that was published:

http://www.thetechherald.com/articles/Report-Analysis-of-the-Stratfor-Password-List