# Does it take longer to brute force a password starting with z than one starting with a?

Tags: passwords, brute-force

I was wondering about the following:

If someone tries to get my password with Brute Force, will a password starting with "a" guessed faster than one starting with "z" ?
In this case assume the password is not salted, just hashed.

Does a Brute Force attack start with "a", try and then go on or compute all hashes first and then see if any matches?

Comment: I've found similar questions like http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53093/are-some-passwords-more-vulnerable-to-password-crackers?rq=1 , but no matching answers for my particular question.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I've found an answer now... Although my second question about the actual difference remains.

Comment: Seems like you have answered your own question?

Comment: Erm, because the alphabet begins with a ? ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say **yes**. Not in any meaningful way (do not base you passwords on this), but still.

## Letter Frequency

First of all, if you follow this rule, your password contains a 'z' instead of an 'a'. The letter 'a' occurs a lot more [frequently in English text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language) than the letter 'z' (this is also true for the [beginning of a word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_the_first_letters_of_a_word_in_the_English_language)), and as such it will be part of words in a wordlist more frequently. Also, many cracking mechanisms (such as [John the Rippers Incremental mode](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/MODES.shtml)) will probably crack a password containing an 'a' instead of a 'z' quicker. This is only a side-effect of your rule, but it is still relevant. And it does make it more probable that passwords starting with an 'a' are cracked than passwords starting with a 'z'.

## Desperate cracking methods

Lets say that the cracker did all the common stuff first: wordlists, etc. They where not successfull. Now they might actually try passwords systematically (note that this will generally be the very last thing they try). Starting with `a,b,...,z,aa,ab,...` and so on. In this case, passwords starting with `a` would be cracked sooner. But it is highly unlikely that the attacker would just stop at `azzz` and not try `bzzz,...zzzz` as well. It would just take a bit longer

Again, this is not in any way actually meaningful. I would say that it does have an effect, but this effect can be neglected in the real world.

## Your additional question

No, an attacker will not first compute all hashes (**all hashes** is a pretty big group), and compare them only at the end. They will compute one hash, compare it, compute another hash, compare it, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know. And by all hashed I meant like all 4 char hashes, try, all 5 char hashes ... and so on, but you explained that as well so it doesn't matter ;).

Comment: When "cracking" hashes you don't necessarily look for the exact same password, just for something that will generate the same hash as the password. Hash collisions. In this case the strength of the password doesn't really matter, the strength of the hash does.

Comment: @BadSkillz in most cases the password is significantly shorter than the hash. So it's unlikely that there will be another password of comparable length with the same hash.

Comment: @PeterGreen When using MD5 it is pretty cheap to look for a collision, so instead of looking for the password, you can look for something that generates the same hash and use that as the password. In that sense the type of hash method is just as important as the strength of the password.

Comment: @BadSkillz there is a difference between a collision attack and a preimage attack. A collision attack gives you two blocks of data that produce the same hash, possiblly with partial but not complete control over what is in the blocks. A preimage attack gives you an input for an existing hash. No computationally feasible preimage attack on MD5 is known.

Answer (score 16):

In general, attackers are adaptive. They know what people think. If users tend to begin their passwords with 'z' then attackers will start their brute force with that letter.

Any specific strategy, such as choosing a 'z' as first letter, may give you an edge over the attacker only as long as the attacker does not know it; so talking about it on a public Q&A site is not the smartest move ever. Moreover, attackers always have the option to try passwords in a random order, which ensures a non-worst case for the attacker. When there are *N* equiprobable passwords, the average cost for the attacker is *N/2* tries, and by trying the passwords in a random order, the attacker achieve that cost regardless of your choosing strategy.

The **important point** is that password protection is stochastic. For any specific password instance, an attacker can get lucky; he can also be especially unlucky. We thus analyse password resistance based on the *password generation process*, not based on a specific password instance: the generation process tells us what will be the *average* success rate of the attacker. "Average" is the crucial word.

Take note, too, that probabilities rule your life: whenever you get out of your home, you are taking the probabilistic bet that you will not be struck by lightning or bitten by an rampaging Rottweiler. You accept this because you instinctively perform a cost/benefit analysis and consider that such events are sufficiently improbable that they don't outweigh the benefits of being able to walk outside.

That concept just applies to passwords as well: you will rely on your password generation process having sufficiently high *entropy*, i.e. making attacker's success rate sufficiently low, that attackers will not even try (or won't succeed with high enough probability). In that sense, "aaaaaaaa" is not stronger or weaker than "zzzzzzzz", as long as the method you use to generate your password can produce both with equal probabilities. The strength of a password is not in what it is, but in what it could have been.

Comment: That's a nice answer. And I was asking just out of curiosity, so I am fine with revealing my secret method of password generation :D The point was more about the methodology of a Brute Force Attack, and "aaaaa" and "zzzzz" were mere examples. But your answer got that point, therefore my +1 ;)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the N/2 rule when it comes to randomly picking from N passwords.

Answer (score 5):

First, most tools/websites like "HowSecureIsMyPassword" do not only consider bruteforce attacks but also dictionary and  rainbow attacks, as well as simple rules such as password length, character pool, use of words, etc. Hence passwords like `aaaaaaa` and `ZZZZZZZ`, will most of the time be evaluated the same way.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no "common" method of starting a bruteforce sequence apart from the simple `a` to `ZZZZZZ` (chosen to illustrate a point and not particular words/strings).

Answering your last question rises more questions: how "fast" is the bruteforce process (also depending on many things), what do you understand by "difference to calculate". In particular you can calculate the total pool of passwords and make some evaluation form there.

About the `144 quadrillion` bruteforce for 1 year, I could say that this number also depends on quite a lot of factors. First, can we run unlimited bruteforce attempts? If we are submitting to a form which computes the hash, this will significantly reduce the "speed". If we are (offline/online) bruteforcing a hash, then we are talking about larger pools (`128/256/512/1024` bits hashes). Second, looking into more practical aspect, is the password that "valuable" to spend 1 year on it and will it be relevant after that period.

Answer (score 2):

Entropy matters more than starting letter.  A competent brute force attack should sort guesses by frequency of use rather than alphabetically.  If they are foolish and go alphabetically, then there would be an advantage, but if your passwords is zebra and my password is `a#4difk*`, your password is going to be guessed FAR sooner as a frequency based word list will guess zebra relatively early but will not guess my password until it starts trying every possible combination.

Even if your password is `zf894SZD`, it would be hard to tell which would be reached first because different crackers will use different approaches to making guesses.  For truly random, they may actually decide to flip things on their head and go with least common letter choices first assuming that someone may have thought they would be extra smart instead of going truly random.  You really can't tell.

The best password is one that is actually high entropy, which means there is no system an attacker could happen to match.  It is simply a large amount of random data that has no quick path to guessing it because there is no pattern at all.

Answer (score 2):

Only depends on how well written the software is. Poorly written which starting at "a" then yes more secure.

Otherwise, parallel programming (Of course this can be programmed differently and optimised by compiler etc).

Let's not other complicate it and keep it simple and say that each core has same amount of data to process and there are no other processes going to be used by Core 0 and 1.

- Core 0 will work from A up to M (which is half of the alphabet)
- Core 1 will work from Z down to N (which is other half of the alphabet)

Reason it works down is incase Core 0 is doing work faster than Core 1 so, it can take over next processing before moving on.

So, your question should be against a software been used for brute forcing really.

Answer (score 1):

Given two options `A****` and `Z****`, you can't know how the attacker works, from A to Z or from Z to A. He might even start from the end of the word: `****A` or `****Z`. If you want to be sure about this, add an extra character to your password, and then maybe M is the more safe choice, safe in the middle.

You cannot depend on one single character for your security. If that is the case, or if that is your concern, add one more. If you don't, remove one character when calculating the strength of it.

Answer (score 0):

No a password starting with z is not more secure. Brute force attacks often use dictionaries to iterate through a possible list of passwords. It will eventually arrive at the entries starting with z. Note that some dictionaries do not list the passwords alphabetically but according to the frequency a password can occur (based on previous experience); like `password1234$` or `zzzzz`.

Even if the Brute Force attack calculates password permutations without a dictionary it still, in the end, arrive at the passwords starting with z.

The best way to mitigate on Brute Force attacks is to enforce complex passwords, account lock out mechanisms (although this invites DDOS) or implement strong Intrusion Detection Rules.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my point clear, I will change the title. The point of my question is, does is take longer before my "zzzzzzz" pw is guessed, because it will be tried at last, or does a Brute Force attacker compute all hased, before comparing them?

Answer (score 0):

Brute force is an approach not a specific program. Brute force has as its goal to cover all possible passwords, but how the algorithm is implemented is specific to a programmers approach. One may start at a, others may start with the most commonly used letter. Tomorrow someone may come up with a new approach.

There are precomputed lists of hashes already available. For example the MD5 hash of `zzzzz` is `95ebc3c7b3b9f1d2c40fec14415d3cb8`. Plug that into [Reverse Hash Calculator](https://isc.sans.edu/tools/reversehash.html) and you get `zzzzz` back in 5 seconds.

You should not depend on tricks like being creative with your password, but rather use strong passwords with randomly-generated characters. Another approach is to use a sentence with several words that you can remember and then use the first letter of each. A password manager is also possible. For online passwords I prefer [PwdHash](http://PwdHash.com) with a single strong password so I can use a single password across multiple sites without worry. I now prefer this over password managers because of the simplicity, even though I still use a password manager.